# Loop over 2D Array Is not showing saved values

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that im looping over an 2d array in a function but I can't get the previously saved values.

This is my code:

```
Dim RowCountTemp As Integer
Dim ColumCountTemp As Integer
Dim MonthArray, ColumnArray
Dim NewTable() As String
Dim NewTableLen As Integer
NewTableLen = 0
        
MonthArray = Array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")
ColumnArray = Array("A", "B", "C")
For Each MonthTemp In MonthArray

    With Worksheets(MonthTemp).ListObjects(MonthTemp)
        RowCountTemp = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        ColumCountTemp = .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

        For i = 1 To RowCountTemp
                        
            Dim RucTemp As String
            Dim CantTemp As String
            Dim Index As Integer
                    
            RucTemp = .Range(i + 1, 1)
            CantTemp = .Range(i + 1, 3)
                        
            Index = Contains(NewTable, NewTableLen, RucTemp)
            If Index > 0 Then
                NewTable(Index, 3) = NewTable(Index, 3) + CantTemp
                Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(2) & Index + 1) = NewTable(Index, 3)
            Else
                NewTableLen = NewTableLen + 1
                'Added Preserve from comment but it throws subindex out of range for the second value added
                ReDim Preserve NewTable(NewTableLen, 3)
                NewTable(NewTableLen, 1) = .Range(i + 1, 1)
                NewTable(NewTableLen, 2) = .Range(i + 1, 2)
                NewTable(NewTableLen, 3) = .Range(i + 1, 3)
                Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(0) & NewTableLen + 1) = NewTable(NewTableLen, 1)
                Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(1) & NewTableLen + 1) = NewTable(NewTableLen, 2)
                Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(2) & NewTableLen + 1) = NewTable(NewTableLen, 3)
            End If
                            
        Next

    End With
    
Next
```

**And my function**

```
Function Contains(Array2D() As String, Length As Integer, SearchFor As String) As Integer
    For i = 1 To Length
        Contains = 0
        If Array2D(i, 1) = SearchFor Then
            Contains = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

For instance, when I read the first sheet, `January`, I save data correctly and I can see it when evaluate `Array2D(i, 1)`, but for the next sheets, when I evaluate `Array2D(i, 1)`, it gives me empty values for all the index stored in past sheets.

Let's suppose `January` sheet gets 2 rows with values `aaaa` and `bbbb`, so, the code allow me to watch `aaaa` stored when evaluates `bbbb`, but in `february` sheet which has `aaaa`, `bbbb` and `cccc`, when `Array2D(i, 1)` is evaluated until `i = 2` for `aaaa`, `i = 3` for `bbbb` and `i = 4` for `cccc`, the values are empty `""` for `aaaa`, but for `bbbb` and `cccc`, it shows me `aaaa` and `bbbb` respectively from `february` sheet so the values are being saved twice

Edit:

1. I have realized that every time I redeem the previous ones are deleted and the last one is saved
2. I added Preserve but it throws me subindex out of range for the second value added

Comment: Is `Redeem preserve` you are looking for?

Comment: I will update because i already did but it throws me subindex out of range :(

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` and declaring *all* of your variables might help.

Comment: Hello @JohnColeman but in wich line should i place it, thanks

Comment: You place it at the top of all your code modules. You can enforce the decision once and for all by enabling "Require Variable Declarations" in the VBA editor options (under "Tools"). In this code, it might not help you, but sooner rather than later you will save yourself a lot of debugging grief.

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman but didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end i changed the code a little bit to achieve those results.

Here is

```
Dim RowCountTemp As Integer
Dim ColumCountTemp As Integer
Dim MonthArray, ColumnArray
Dim NewTable() As String
Dim NewTableLen As Integer
NewTableLen = 0
        
MonthArray = Array("Enero2020", "Febrero2020", "Marzo2020", "Abril2020", "Mayo2020", "Junio2020", "Julio2020", "Agosto2020", "Septiembre2020", "Octubre2020", "Noviembre2020", "Diciembre2020", "Enero2021", "Febrero2021", "Marzo2021", "Abril2021", "Mayo2021")
ColumnArray = Array("A", "B", "C")

For Each MonthTemp In MonthArray


    With Worksheets(MonthTemp).ListObjects(MonthTemp)
        RowCountTemp = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        ColumCountTemp = .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
        'If MonthTemp = "Abril2021" Or MonthTemp = "Mayo2021" Then
            For i = 1 To RowCountTemp
                    
                Dim RucTemp As String
                Dim CantTemp As String
                Dim Index As Integer
                
                RucTemp = .Range(i + 1, 1)
                CantTemp = .Range(i + 1, 3)
                
                Index = Contains(NewTable, NewTableLen, RucTemp)
                If Index > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(2) & Index + 1) = Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(2) & Index + 1) + CantTemp
                Else
                    NewTableLen = NewTableLen + 1
                    ReDim Preserve NewTable(NewTableLen)
                    NewTable(NewTableLen) = .Range(i + 1, 1)
                    Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(0) & NewTableLen + 1) = NewTable(NewTableLen)
                    Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(1) & NewTableLen + 1) = .Range(i + 1, 2)
                    Worksheets("Resumen").Range(ColumnArray(2) & NewTableLen + 1) = .Range(i + 1, 3)
                End If
                    
            Next
        'End If
    End With
    
Next
    


Function Contains(Array2D() As String, Length As Integer, SearchFor As String) As Integer
    For i = 1 To Length
        Contains = 0
        If Array2D(i) = SearchFor Then
            Contains = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```